# .vimrc not being sourced when i save or source the file manually

Tags: macos, vim

When i write to file, the .vimrc file is not being sourced, meaning i am having to close the terminal then restart.

I have tried.
    `:source $MYVIMRC`, 
    `:so $MYVIMRC`,
    `:source ~/.vimrc`,
    `:source ~/.vimrc`
Also i have tried to implement it this way. I am using, Mac osx, Yosemite. vim nocompatible mode.

```
augroup reload_vimrc " {
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
augroup END " }
```

Comment: can you include the result of echo $MYVIMRC

Comment: `:echo $MYVIMRC` is `/Users/********/.vimrc`

Comment: Sourcing your vimrc is not really a good idea because it only sources your vimrc and not your plugins or whatever. It doesn't even set filetype again. If you want to test new options/mappings, start a new vim session.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **"** or  **{** like the code below

```
augroup reload_vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source $MYVIMRC
augroup END
```

Comment: no still not working. it seems to work in as much as my cursor resets to top of file, like it would when the file is written. `nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<CR>` Is a test mapping that when resourced /saved should take effect, but doesn't. When i quit vim and come back in, it works?

Comment: put the line **au BufWritePost .vimrc source ~/.vimrc** at the bottom of your VIMRC. and test it.

Comment: The " { does not matter, since this is a comment.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try and resolve this for me, i have just tried   byaruhaf's answer, that was also how i had used the `au BufWritePost .vimrc source ~/.vimrc` when on ubunt unfortunately still no response?